# Spring GWT integration

Tags: spring, gwt, servlets, service, rpc

I'm writing the code for a console using GWT and Spring integration. I have followed GWT tutorial and read some forums about how to use spring qith GWT.

I'm at the point that the RPC call is returning null and I can't seem to see why. As english is not my native language and I'm pretty new to this, I'm just going to put my code here to see if someone can help me with it.

Service:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("GestionUserService")
public interface GestionUserService extends RemoteService {
    Collection<Usuario> dameTablaUsuarios(String entidad);

}
```

Async:

```
public interface GestionUserServiceAsync {
    void dameTablaUsuarios(String entidad,AsyncCallback<Collection<Usuario>> callback);

}
```

Impl:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Service("GestionUserService")
public class GestionUsersConsultImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GestionUserService {

@Autowired
UserConsoleDBUtil utilDB;
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GestionUsersConsultImpl.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Usuario> dameTablaUsuarios(String entidad) {
    GWT.log("Log");
    logger.info("He llegado al IMPL dameTablaUsuarios.======================="+entidad);
    logger.info("UtilDB "+utilDB.toString());
    return utilDB.getDao().getUsuarios(entidad);
}
```

}

*gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='userConsole'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

    <!-- Compilar solamente para Firefox -->
    <!--<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"></set-property> -->

    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.client.GestionUsers' />


    <!-- English language, independent of country -->
    <extend-property name="locale" values="es_ES" />
    <extend-property name="locale" values="en_US" />
    <extend-property name="locale" values="de_DE" />

    <!-- Specify the application specific style sheet. -->
    <stylesheet src='UserConsole.css' />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='client/services' />
    <source path='db/bean' />
</module>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans>

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole" />

    <!--  FIN Agregado de la consola gwt-spring -->

    <import resource="config.xml" />

    <util:constant id="VARCHAR" static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="GestionUserService" class="com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.server.GestionUsersConsultImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="utilDB" class="com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.db.UserConsoleDBUtil">
        <property name="dao" ref="UserConsoleDAO" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

config.xml

```
<beans >


    <bean id="UserConsoleDAO" class="com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.db.UserConsoleDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />

        <!-- Definicion de consultas -->
        <property name="sqlUsuarios"
            value=" SELECT DISTINCT (IDUSER) IDUser,
                                    NOMBRE Nombre,
                                    IDPerfil IDPerfil,
                                    FECHAALTA FechaAlta,
                                    FECHABAM FechaBAM,
                                    FECHACON FechaConsola
                                FROM
                                    A_APAMA.USERS
                                WHERE
                                    EMPRESA=?" />

        <property name="sqlUsuarios2"
            value=" SELECT DISTINCT (IDUSER) IDUser
                                FROM
                                    A_APAMA.USERS
                                WHERE
                                    EMPRESA=?" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:db2://udisapma.isban.dev.corp:60090/udisapma" />
        <property name="username" value="a_apama" />
        <property name="password" value="********" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And finally my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Loads and makes available the context defined in springconfig-service.xml -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>gestionUsersConsultImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.server.GestionUsersConsultImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>gestionUsersConsultImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/userConsole/GestionUserService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>GestionUsers.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Paginas de error -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/accessDeny.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/serverError.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

In my main class i have this:

```
AsyncCallback<Collection<Usuario>> getUserID2 = new AsyncCallback<Collection<Usuario>>() {
            // Failure: muestra error
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                whatever;
            }

            // Succes: obtener usuario
            public void onSuccess(Collection<Usuario> Users) {
                Whatever;
            }
        };
        gestionUservc.dameTablaUsuarios("3293", getUserID2);
```

Edit: In case its useful here is the error:

com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.Collection com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.client.GestionUserService.dameTablaUsuarios(java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:378)    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:581)     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:207)   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:243)   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null    at com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.server.GestionUsersConsultImpl.dameTablaUsuarios(GestionUsersConsultImpl.java:31)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:207)   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:243)   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

Edit 2: And here what my log is saying:

2013-02-25 16:20:02,424 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2013-02-25 16:20:02,453 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Feb 25 16:20:02 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-02-25 16:20:02,496 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
2013-02-25 16:20:02,696 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config.xml]
2013-02-25 16:20:02,724 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
2013-02-25 16:20:02,724 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Overriding bean definition for bean 'GestionUserService': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.server.GestionUsersConsultImpl]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [D:\Workspace\USER_CONSOLE\target\UserConsole\WEB-INF\classes\com\santander\bam\comun\userconsole\server\GestionUsersConsultImpl.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.server.GestionUsersConsultImpl]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
2013-02-25 16:20:02,803 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3f96ee: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,GestionUserService,UserConsoleDAO,myDataSource,transactionManager,VARCHAR,utilDB]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-02-25 16:20:02,890 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 466 ms
2013-02-25 16:20:10,020 INFO  [com.santander.bam.comun.userconsole.server.GestionUsersConsultImpl] - He llegado al IMPL dameTablaUsuarios.=======================3293

Answer (score 0):

It seems in method `dameTablaUsuarios(String entidad)`

The line `logger.info("UtilDB "+utilDB.toString());` causing `nullpointer exception`.`utilDB` is `null`.Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added that line to make sure that my DAO was null, if i take that line out I'm still getting the same error, so i think my utilDB object is null at that point, but i fail to see why.

Comment: I would have done that if I could, but i can't seem to get the debug mode working, maybe I'm doing something rong, but I run the app on debug mode with a breakpoint when I'm going to make the async call and it doesnt seem to start debugging, this is what i get on the console: Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000, so it stays there waiting for me to do something, but i don't know what.

Comment: OK, so i finally managed to get it working. This is my solution:

         <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>userConsole/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("springGwtServices/GestionUserService")

Thanks a lot for everyonw to take the time to help me, and sorry for lack of knowledge. This also helped me to find the answer: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-uml-designer/source/browse/trunk/GWTUMLDrawer/?r=8

Comment: Cheers :) that's great for found the solution on your own,Sorry for didn't push you further due to time limits.